# Kann so bedeuten zu sagen?

Tags: meaning

Today's Langsamer Nachrichten from DW contains the following sentence:

> Unter belgischer Regentschaft sei es im Kongo zu Gewalt und Grausamkeiten gekommen, die auf dem kollektiven Gedächtnis lasten, so der König.

», so der König.« appears to mean, ", said the King." But since when is "so" a verb? If someone can point me to the relevant Duden definition I would be obliged.

Comment: Well, it answers part of the question. Is this an example where Duden is not the final authority on the German language, then?

Comment: It is [Duden entry 1b](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_derartig_solch_genauso_etwa#Bedeutung1b) "mit Ellipse des Verbs bei Zitaten oder Quellenangaben; mit diesen Worten, in diesem Sinne äußert[e] sich …, steht es in …
Beispiel: man setzt hier ein Komma, so der Duden"

Comment: Thank you for siting this. The answer is complete.